# How to correctly use weatherbit.io api in android app

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using a `get` request to get weather data using api from `weatherbit.io`. How do I use the `base Url` and the `relative url` correctly.

I've tried to use `base url` inside my main activity and the `relative url` inside the interface I've created.But I'm not getting any output in the textview

My main activity:

```
 Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
 OpenWeatherMapApi openWeatherMapApi=retrofit.create(OpenWeatherMapApi.class);

   Call<List<Post>> call=openWeatherMapApi.getPosts("my_city_name","my_country_name","my_key");
```

my retrofit interface:

```
@GET("forecast/daily")
Call<List<Post>> getPosts(@Query("city")String city,@Query("country")String country,@Query("key")String key);
```

Comment: you'd better describe the error you ran into.

Comment: I think you need to pass api key as well.

Comment: I passed the api key in relative url